# Scrapy handle 301/302 response code as well as follow the target url

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy version 1.0.5 for implementation of a crawler. Currently I have set `REDIRECT_ENABLED = False` and `handle_httpstatus_list = [500, 301, 302]` to scrape the pages with 301 and 302 responses. However, since `REDIRECT_ENABLED` is set to `False`, the spider doesn't goes to the target url in `Location` response header. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: how are you handling 301 and 302 in your callback? can you share spider code?

Comment: @paultrmbrth aren't the redirects supposed to be crawled?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "crawled". By default, Scrapy issues Requests for HTTP 30x responses, without passing the responses to callbacks. By default, Scrapy will only pass on to callbacks responses with HTTP status 200. If 30x codes are in `handle_httpstatus_list`, the middleware handling automatic following of redirects will have no effect. and the callback with receive the "raw" response, for which one needs to interpret the headers and/or body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a long tome since I did anything like this but you need to generate a request object with url, meta and callback parameters.

But I seem to recall you can do it along the lines of:

```
def parse(self,response):
    # do whatever you need to do .... then
    if response.status in [301, 302] and 'Location' in response.headers:
        # test to see if it is an absolute or relative URL
        newurl = urljoin(request.url, response.headers['location'])
        # or 
        newurl = response.headers['location']
        yield Request(url = newurl, meta = request.meta, callback=self.parse_whatever)
```