# How to integrate several 'yield' commands together in scrapy script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

My issue is that when I added the redirect code from [Can't get Scrapy to parse and follow 301, 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776377/cant-get-scrapy-to-parse-and-follow-301-302-redirects) to my script, it solved the problem in that now it runs without errors, but now I'm not getting any output to my csv file. The problem is that in parse_links1, the if and else statements end with a 'yield' statement and this seems to be preventing the scrapy.Request line from implementing. This is fairly clear since in the previous iteration of this code, which only went down 2 levels of links, the code ran perfectly. But since the latest level has a redirect issue, I had to add that code in.

My code is like this:

```
    class TurboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "fourtier"
        handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
        start_urls = [
         "https://ttlc.intuit.com/browse/cd-download-support"]
        # def parse gets first set of links to use
        def parse(self, response):

            links = response.selector.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, 
         "list-unstyled")]//@href').extract()
            for link in links:
                 yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_links, 
                   dont_filter=True)


        def parse_links(self, response):
            tier2_text = response.selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class, 
    "dropdown-item-link")]//@href').extract()
            for link in tier2_text:
                schema = 'https://turbotax.intuit.com/'
                links_to_use = urlparse.urljoin(schema, link)
                yield scrapy.Request(links_to_use, self.parse_links1)


        def parse_links1(self, response):
            tier2A_text = response.selector.xpath('//a').extract()

            for t in tier2A_text:
                if response.status >= 300 and response.status < 400:
                   # HTTP header is ascii or latin1, redirected url will be percent-encoded utf-8
                  location= 
           to_native_str(response.headers['location'].decode('latin1'))
                    request = response.request
                    redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, location)
                    if response.status in (301, 307) or request.method 
                    == 'HEAD':
                        redirected = 
                    request.replace(url=redirected_url)
                        yield redirected
                    else:
                        redirected = 
            request.replace(url=redirected_url, 
                    method='GET', body='')
                        redirected.headers.pop('Content-Type', None)
                        redirected.headers.pop('Content-Length', None)
                        yield redirected
                    yield scrapy.Request((t, self.parse_links2))


        def parse_links2(self, response):
            divs = response.selector.xpath('//div')
            for p in divs.select('.//p'):
                yield{'text':p.extract()}
```

What is wrong with the way I've set up the 'yield' in the parse_links1 function so that now I don't get any output? How to integrate several 'yield' commands together?

Comment: The yields are OK. What makes you think they aren’t? Also, se see you always yield `scrapy.Request((t, self.parse_links2))` (regardless of the if statement above); why are you passing a tuple to Request()?

Answer (score 0):

See [Debugging Spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html).

Some logging statements should allow you to determine where something unexpected is happening (execution not reaching a certain line, some variable containing unexpected data), which in turn should help you either understanding what the issue is or writing a more specific question that is easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the debugging options and haven't succeeded in solving the issue yet. I edited the question to try to make it more clear.